# Visual C++ switch control path impasse

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

This yields warning C4715: not all control paths return a value.

```
int f_no_default(bool true_or_false)
{
    switch (true_or_false)
    {
    case (true) :
        return 1;
    case (false) :
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But this yields warning C4809: switch statement has redundant 'default' label; all possible 'case' labels are given.

```
int f_with_default(bool true_or_false)
{
    switch (true_or_false)
    {
    case (true) :
        return 1;
    case (false) :
        return 0;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What can I do? (other than turn off treat warnings as errors)

Visual Studio 2013 V12.0

Comment: clang gives this warning: `main.cpp:5:5: Switch condition has boolean value` - presumably switching on a bool is a bad idea, perhaps if/else is a better option?

Comment: Yeah that's the way I went

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can I do? (other than turn off treat warnings as errors)

The following code might probably fix it:

```
int f_no_default(bool true_or_false)
{
    switch (true_or_false)
    {
    case (true) :
        return 1;
    case (false) :
        return 0;
    }

    return 0; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

That's a silly warning for the case, but the static analysis capabilities depend on the actual compiler implementation, so do the usefulness of warning messages.

---

Another option (more compliant with your function name) would be to throw an exception:

```
int f_no_default(bool true_or_false)
{
    switch (true_or_false)
    {
    case (true) :
        return 1;
    case (false) :
        return 0;
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("Unecpected value for 'true_or_false'");
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you also use a return statement in the default case to solve the warning?

Comment: @Stephen Apparently not with VS 2013.